# getting matrix element using dictionary-like index in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, numpy

Numpy can manipulate matrix. And matrix element can be got via numerical indexes.

Now, say I have a 3*3 square matrix ***M***
(Actually, it is a [Malcov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) transition matrix, where each element speaks the probability from one state switching to another).

And the row and column both represent `rain`, `snow`, `niceday` in order.

```
[0.5 ,0.25,0.25
 1   , 0  , 0
 0.25,0.25,0.5]
```

Ordinarily, if I want to get the (rain,snow) element, I would have to write ***M[0,1]***.

But I think this is not readable enough.

So I wonder if I can get such element ***M['rain','snow']***, if I have defined such dict-like matrix before(if it is allowed numpy matrix manipulation rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the variables `rain`, `snow` and `niceday` and use this variables instead the numbers

```
rain = 0
snow = 1
M[rain, snow]
```